# How to review all datas in one pages in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have five pages in asp.net web application. I entered information in first page and click next. it goes to next page and enter information in this page. I continue this process for five pages. Before click Submit button in fifth page, I need to review once all information entered by me in all previous pages under review button click. How do this? pls Advice.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CHwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmattgemmell.com%2F2008%2F12%2F08%2Fwhat-have-you-tried%2F&ei=UDaqT8mSBIPi4QTlsb28CQ&usg=AFQjCNF5YOT1O7kvNT_JGM-bDOiVdCSrHQ&sig2=hiOIVrt1O2sRBSZa5eEpOA)?

Answer (score 1):

You can store your data in the database, as you move along the steps, and retrieve it in the final step. You can also store it in Session, as an alternative.

Surely there are other ways to implement this scenario, but the idea is to somehow persist the data and retrieve it in the final step.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that you are going the wrong way about this. Passing data from page to page is going to cause you all sorts of trouble.

There are a number of methods to achieve this on a single page. You could create 5 seperate controls and place them all on the single page (if they aren't all too big and slow down the page load), then make the appropriate control visible depending on which the user is to see. For example, when you click next make the current control visible property false and then display the next one. Then at the end of the process when you click complete you can access the entered data from each of the controls, you could create a fancy function in the controls that return you a populated class or even pass by reference (we won't go in to that here).

You could also look in to using [Views](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_multi_views.htm). Which is another method that you could implement on a singular page.

If you're adamant with using multiple pages then you could temporarily store the data in a database and then on the final page get the IDs from a Session and store it all finally as one. But I wouldn't advise this, although it depends on the situation. If you want them to be able to fill half the form and then continue at a later date then the database method would be advisable, but if you only want data being stored upon completion then you will end up with a lot of half completed redundant data using this method.

Answer (score 0):

The solution totally depends on the framework and methods you are using. I'll try and help you with an ASP.Net MVC3 solution, as I think MVC3 is really the way to go for when using ASP.Net.

- When the user clicks on the 'next' button, just load a partial view (containing the next step html) with the JavaScript / jQuery Ajax method, OR just present the next step by using using the jQuery show / hide functions.
- Keep your form data within one html form-tag (or at least one holder-div).
- When you need to submit the information at the last step, simply collect the information with a single jQuery serialize call and send it to your ASP.Net receiver.

Some code snippets:
Display a partial view from the Razor view-engine:
`@Html.Partial("/Views/Instance/_General.cshtml", Model)`
Load a partial view through jQuery - for more details, please see http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/
`@Html.Partial("/Views/Instance/_General.cshtml", Model)`

Post your data to the server though jQuery:

```
$("#submit-button-id").click(function () {
    var data = $("#form-id").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Example/Save",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function (success) {
            if (success) {
                // things worked out just fine..
            }
            else {
                // present some kind of error..
            }
        }
    });
});
```